# Import/convert list of space separated numbers to list of arrays in Matlab

Tags: string, excel, matlab, vector

I'm new to Matlab and I want to convert a column with space separated numbers (source is an Excel file) to a list of arrays.

[image]

In a first step I want to create a list of arrays like this:

[image]

Then I want to transpose the list like this:

[image]

Whats the correct command for this conversion?

I know it's a simple question, but I couldn't find a similar one.

Comment: Define *list* of vectors. Do you mean a cell array? And what exactly is your input? A 2d character array, or a single string with newlines?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with MATLAB's built-in data structures: arrays and cells, mostly. Parts of your question suggest that you're not really clear on the subject. Also, check out first how you can import data from excel; this might already guide you or limit your options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`xlsread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) to read in the raw text.  The text will be read in as a cell array where each row of text is placed in a cell.  Once you do this, it's a matter of splitting up the strings by spaces to create an additional cell array of cells per row, then inputting these cells into a function that creates an array of numbers.  You can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) combined with [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html).  Assuming your Excel file is called `list.xls`, do something like this:

```
[~,~,RAW] = xlsread('list.xls');
list = cellfun(@str2double, cellfun(@strsplit, RAW, 'uni', 0), 'uni', 0).';
```

`list` contains the desired output.  I've also transposed the result as this is what you desire.  I created an Excel file that's in the same fashion as how you've mentioned in your post.  This is what I get when I run the code.  First I'll show what `list` looks like, then we'll examine what the actual contents are:

```
>> list

list = 

    [1x4 double]    [1x5 double]    [1x6 double]

>> celldisp(list)

list{1} =

        5405        5414        5420        9999



list{2} =

        5405        5414        5430        5341        9999



list{3} =

        5405        5419        5419        5419        5412        9999
```

Here's also what the MATLAB Variable Editor looks like:

[image]